# Adding fat library to XCFramework not working in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode, xcode12, xcframework, apple-silicon

> ***Edit** (2020/09/14)*: This appears to have been an Xcode bug that has now been fixed as of Xcode 12 beta 6.

I am using Xcode 12 to build a static library, and for tvOS, Xcode 12 includes both `arm64` and `arm64e` in the single fat library.

Similarly, when building for the Simulator, Xcode 12 includes both `x86_64` and `arm64` (Mac Apple Silicon) in a single fat library.

In both cases, I am not able to create an XCFramework that includes these libraries, using the command:

`xcodebuild -create-xcframework -output A.xcframework" -library A.a`

Attempting to do so results in the error

`error: unable to find any architecture information in the binary at 'A.a'`

The output from `lipo -info A.a` clearly indicates both architectures present (`arm64` + `arm64e` and `arm64` + `x86_64`, respectively), so I don't understand why `xcodebuild` can't recognize and handle it.

I have also attempted to extract the individual architectures into two thin files each (eg. `A-arm64.a` and `A-arm64e.a`) and then create the XCFramework with those, but that results in a different error:

`Both tvos-arm64e and tvos-arm64 represent two equivalent library definitions.`

and

`Both tvos-arm64-simulator and tvos-x86_64-simulator represent two equivalent library definitions.`

Am I missing something? How does one create an XCFramework from a fat library (or two equivalent thin libraries)?

Comment: AFAICT `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` has a hardcoded list of supported architectures for each platform which was not updated in Xcode 12. It works fine for me when using only architectures supported by Xcode 11, but adding arm64 to a simulator library breaks it and gives this error.

Comment: just check out this might help you https://github.com/bielikb/xcframeworks

Comment: This appears to have been an Xcode bug that has now been fixed as of Xcode 12 beta 6.

Comment: Any updates at present?
Having the same issue trying to create xcframework for sim64/simx86/device64

Result
Both ios-x86_64-simulator and ios-arm64-simulator represent two equivalent library definitions.

Comment: @SergeyBrazhnik Create two separate libraries: one combined (fat) sim64/simx86, and a separate device64 library. Then add them to the XCFramework.

Comment: @BillHollings Can you add your answer please.

Comment: @Ravi Done now. 

In doing so, SO suggests editing the question instead, which is why that's what I had originally done above.

Comment: Also, this might help you: https://github.com/gurhub/surmagic

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been an Xcode bug that has now been fixed as of Xcode 12 beta 6.